# How do I rewrite this recursive call as a loop?

Tags: c#, recursion, windows-runtime

In order to simplify the code so I can understand better, I am trying to convert this recursion call into a while loop:

```
function getMusic(IStorageFolder folder) {
    int cnt = 0;
    var folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();
    if (folders != null)
        foreach (var fol in folders)
            await getMusic(fol);

    var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
        source.Add(new Music("artist", "title", "album");
        cnt++;
    }
}
```

In the code, `source` is an ObservableCollection of type `Music` (contains three parameters as seen in `source.Add...` line).

However, I have been unsuccessful. Here is my attempt at it, which doesn't seem to populate the `source` list.

```
private async Task getMusic(IStorageFolder folder)
{
    Stack<StorageFolder> fold = new Stack<StorageFolder>();
    int count = 0; int firstTen = 0;
    var folders = await folder.GetFoldersAsync();

    foreach (var indvFolder in folders)
        fold.Push(indvFolder);

    while (count < fold.Count)
    {
        var fol = fold.Pop();
        if (firstTen > 9)
            break;
        var files = await fol.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
            source.Add(new Music("artist", "title", "album"));
            count++;
        }
        firstTen++;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you been successful in `Debugging` the code.. can you not understand the foreach loop..?

Comment: I had a `Debug.WriteLine` after every line in the code for checking the values of the variables. I have taken them out of this code to keep it clean.

Comment: so what's your problem / issue do you know how to use the debugger's Quick Watch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do too much all in one function, and that's what complicating the code.  Conceptually you're doing several different things here, getting all of the folders in the tree, getting all of the files from all of the folders, and getting all of the properties from all of the files.  Break up those operations.

Traversing the file system to get all of the files is an operation that you've already pretty much got down.  In fact, since trees like this are going to be traversed the same way all the time, you can even generalize the asynchronous tree traversal into a structure-independent algorithm:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> TraverseAsync<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source
    , Func<T, Task<IEnumerable<T>>> childrenSelector)
{
    var queue = new Queue<T>(source);
    List<T> results = new List<T>();
    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var next = queue.Dequeue();
        results.Add(next);
        foreach (var child in await childrenSelector(next))
            queue.Enqueue(child);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Using this you can now take your starting folder, traverse the graph to get all folders, map those folders to all of the files, and then map those files to all of their properties:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Music>> getMusic(IStorageFolder rootFolder)
{
    var folders = await new[] { rootFolder }
        .TraverseAsync(folder => folder.GetFoldersAsync());
    var files = (await Task.WhenAll(
        folders.Select(folder => folder.GetFilesAsync())))
        .SelectMany(folder => folder);
    var properties = (await Task.WhenAll(
        files.Select(file => file.GetMusicPropertiesAsync())))
        .SelectMany(property => property);
    return properties.Select(prop => new Music());
}
```

This is made a tad messier due to the need to keep everything asynchronous.  If we first make an asynchronous version of `SelectMany`:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectManyAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    this Task<IEnumerable<TSource>> source,
    Func<TSource, Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>> resultSelector)
{
    var sourceSequence = await source;
    var sequences = await Task.WhenAll(sourceSequence.Select(resultSelector));
    return sequences.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

It simplifies the code:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Music>> getMusic(IStorageFolder rootFolder)
{
    var properties = await new[] { rootFolder }
        .TraverseAsync(folder => folder.GetFoldersAsync())
        .SelectManyAsync(folder => folder.GetFilesAsync())
        .SelectManyAsync(file => file.GetMusicPropertiesAsync());
    return properties.Select(prop => new Music());
}
```

Of note here is that we're also ensuring that this method actually returns the results that is has *in the task itself* rather than by mutating a list as a side effect.  This ensures that the `Task` class will be responsible for all of the necessary cross-thread synchronization issues, and ensures that the result collection can't be accessed before the asynchronous operation has actually completed (which is likely where your problem lies).

Answer (score 2):

`fold.Pop()` changes `fold.Count`.  `fold.Count` won't include already-processed items, so `count < fold.Count` is meaningless.

Instead, use `while (fold.Count > 0)`

Also, this stuff should be inside the loop, because the original code visited subfolders of subfolders:

```
foreach (var indvFolder in fol.GetFoldersAsync())
    fold.Push(indvFolder);
```

The setup is just

```
fold.Push(folder);
```